# Capacitor Time Delay circuit not working

Tags: circuit-design, timer, delay

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3mbTT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I made a circuit schematic for a simple discrete capacitor+resistor time delay circuit, using a 1500uf capacitor and a 100kOhm resistor as a timing mechanism. On activation of the momentary push button switch, the capacitor should fill up then slowly discharge through the 100kOhm resistor into both transistors' bases, opening the flow into the other capacitor (connected to transistor 2) which then continually discharges and refills until the first capacitor runs out of charge and the transistor is closed, when the second cap finally discharges through the only open path (through the 10kOhm resistor into the load). When the other transistor is open, it should act as a NOT switch, taking the charge from the second cap and sending it to neutral instead of through the 10kOhm resistor, but instead when I tested the circuit on a perf board with a 3V coin battery cell as a power supply, it provides no output, regardless of whether or not the button is pushed. The LED does not light up either. I have the schematic attached below, I would be very grateful if you could help me find a solution to this, as my first real circuit[image: Attached: Schematic]

Comment: They are both 2N2222 transistors, the caps are electrolytic and momentary switch is a regular SPST switch. All components should be rated to handle more than the voltage provided, I think the problem is with the logic

Comment: What does the (-) and "out" do in your original paper schematic? Do you connect them to something else, not shown? (I don't want to read the added schematic until I understand this aspect.) I think you say it is a "load" but you need to write a lot more about exactly what that load is and, if appropriate, what voltage it requires.

Comment: The out goes to whatever load you want to power, or to another transistor to signal for some other circuit to run. The (-) wire is for it to return in case it is a load. The voltage going to it is not important

Comment: Okay. You want a switch to initiate a time period (I'm confused still about if there is one time period or two time periods involved. But I think just one time period, for now.) You want the output to be the voltage across a capacitor that declines as current leaves through the 10k resistor. And then, at some point -- and this is just a guess, you want the circuit to reset itself so that the push button can re-activate all this. This is a question, not a statement of fact. I'm asking you if my wording is at all close to what you are thinking. Because I really don't know the goal, yet.

Comment: Basically, I want the capacitor to charge up on activation of the button. It then discharges thru the 100kOhm resistor and feeds the 2 transistors. While they are open, the second cap is able to be charged by the battery and continuously charges & discharges through the transistors to ground, until the first cap (time delay) fully discharges and the transistors close. Then the remaining charge in the second capacitor  flows through the 10kOhm resistor for a few seconds, flashing an LED or opening a transistor for a few seconds. Then the circuit is re-armed and waits for next button push.

Comment: Your result is the wrong approach and explanation as well.  Try drawing some pulse wave form of switch input and LED output current.  Then the intermediate pulse signal. The rest will fall into place with proper Vbe vs Ic

Comment: @NewUser I'm probably out of my depth. Or there are language problems. I agree with Tony about the diagrams, though. They'd perhaps help.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will redo the approach. Thank you for helping!